# Mapbox GeolocateControl not working on safari on http://localhost:3000

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, mapbox-gl-js

i am currently developing an Ionic/vuejs App and i need to display the position of the user on a map. I am using Mapbox gl js to display a map and i use the GeolocateController of mapbox. On Android it is working fine but on ios/safari its not working and i get this error message:

```
access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://localhost:3000
```

Apparently the GeolocateController uses the Geolocation API of JavaScript under the hood and safari doesn't allow to locate the user on an unsecure connection. But when developing, i'm on http://localhost:3000 and even when i build the app and deploy on devices, it's still using http://localhost.

Am i missing something important? Or how can i solve this issue?

When i use the Capacitor Plugin Geolocation, i receive the correct data. Is it somehow possible to "overwrite" the GeolocateController of Mapbox to instead use Capacitor Geolocation when trying to locate the user?

"@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0"
"vue": "^3.0.0-0",

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this for a while but haven't found anything. On Mapbox's GeolocateControl object, you can pass a geolocation option to replace the default window.navigator.geolocation. But this still doesn't work even though the capacitor plugin Geolocation works in the app when triggered by something other than the mapbox GeolocateControl button.